# Getting fields via reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I have an object that has been wrapped so whenever i do the following;

```
        Field[] fields = builder.getClass().getDeclaredFields(); 

        String s = "";
        for(Field f : fields)
        {
            s+= " " + f.getName();
        }
```

I get fields that aren't in my class. If i want to modify a field that ahs been wrapped, is it possible to do so via reflection?

Thanks

edit: yes i called it on the unwrapped object. Sorry - its been a long day :/

Comment: Not sure what you mean--that method returns exactly what it says it does; if you want the fields of the class that's wrapped, call it on that class. Can you provide more details of what you have, and what you want?

Comment: It might help us to post your expected output, and your actual output.

Comment: please use StringBuffer to build strings like that in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `builder.getClass()` returns the wrong class. You might have to look up the wrapped object and call `getClass()` on it or - if you can change the builder - provide a method to get the class of the wrapped object.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean change the value of the field? you could call `f.set(builder, <value>)`. not sure what you mean by wrapped object, may be you want to unwrap it before you perform the do the reflection magic

Comment: only if you call `f.setAccessible(true);` first

Answer (score 0):

First you can use `YourClass.getDeclaredFields()`  instead of attempting to access the fields using object `builder`:  `builder.getClass().getDeclaredFields();`

Second, if your class is wrapped by other class it means that outer object holds reference to inner one (hopefully yours). So you have to discover the outer object to see which fields does it have and which field holds reference to your inner object. Then call `inner =outer.getField("theFiledName").getValue(builder)`.

Now you can use `inner` exactly as you tried in your code snippet.